# Can Squid be configured to use the incoming IP address as the outgoing Address if multiple IPs are used on the server?

Tags: proxy, bind, squid

At the moment I have to define rules for all local ips like this:

```
acl ip1 localip 1.1.1.1/32
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.1 ip1
acl ip2 localip 2.2.2.2/32
tcp_outgoing_address 2.2.2.2 ip2
acl ip3 localip 3.3.3.3/32
tcp_outgoing_address 3.3.3.3 ip3
```

As I need to configure several server adn they always have different ips I would like to configure squid in a way that always the same address that is used as incoming address is also used as outgoing address.

Is this possible?

I am also open to other solutions. I tried tinyproxy, which has the "bindsame" option for this, but lacks the possibility to define external authentication scripts.
I also need external authentication via a program which squid is able to do.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm looking to setup something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: We should open a feature request for Squid. This would be a very useful feature and many people are looking to have it.

Comment: yeah i agree @Arya it would benefit the project

Comment: Did you find any new solution? I tried DeleGate, but it does not support specify outgoing interface.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: Based on my research, squid does not support anything like tinyproxy's "BindSame".

**Details**: I have been researching this very topic because I am in precisely the same situation as you: I want to use tinyproxy for the BindSame configuration, but I need authentication, which tinyproxy does not support. Unfortunately, my conclusion is that squid does not have an equivalent to tinyproxy's BindSame. I can see no other directive that could be used to specify the outgoing IP address.

From [squid reference documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/tcp_outgoing_address/), we see that the tcp_outgoing_address directive requires a specific IP address as an argument. It won't accept something like "same" or a variable from a matching ACL.

I wish I had a more favorable answer for you, because if I did, I'd be using it, too!

Comment: I have been using Tinyproxy, but I have found out that it becomes unresponsive after 1-2 days of just running on my server. Have you had a similar issue?

Comment: @Arya Yes, i had similar issue for Tinyproxy.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want (if I read your question correctly) is [Tproxy](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4) - this effectively makes squid IP transparent - it will look like the client is making the proxied requests.

To be honest, it's a bit of a faff to set up (more than a couple of directives), but it does work.

Comment: I'm looking to setup tproxy setup with Squid but I have not been successful so far as the guide on Squid is outdated. I can use Centos or Debian. What guide did you use to setup your system?